# Working with strings in c and c++

Tags: c, string, char, constants, formatted

I am not sure exactly how to pass different string types to functions in C.

I have a function that receives a formatted string

```
void Logger::info(const char *logstring, ...) 
{

    // So I basically can write a preliminary message "DATA:" to a buffer
    // and then use vsnprintf() to write the const char *logstring to the buffer as well.

    int offset = 0;
    va_list argp;
    char buf[STRSIZE + 1];

    va_start(argp, logstring);
    offset = sprintf(buf, "DATA: ");
    vsnprintf(&buf[offset], STRSIZE - offset, logstring, argp);
    va_end(argp);

    // Then I write the buffer to stderr

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buf);
}
```

What I would like to do is move all of that deeper into the function. But I cannot make it work because I have no idea how to successfully pass the formatted string "logstring" to the function and have it come out the other side.

So I want to do it like this...

```
info(const char *logstring, ...)
{
    writeToFile("Data:",logstring);
}
```

Then I can have the log file writing done more centrally.

Comment: Are you asking how to send the variadic parameters from your top function to the writeToFile() function? Or how to perform the format and then just send the preamble and formatted data to writeToFile() ? Perhaps neither and you're asking something else? Sry, just a little confused at the question.

Comment: Pretty much either. I want to be able to pass "const char *logstring" to a function. So if I can either just need to change my function variable to something accept it or just convert it to something that will pass through than all the better. I would give examples of what I've tried but it would muddy things since they didn't work. Either somehow coming out as a one character string or losing the formatted variables that were supposed to be in the string.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. I can try and craft up an answer, but I think just telling you that you *can* create a function that takes a va_list as a parameter (in fact, vsnprintf is an example of such a thing). Ironic since the code you have here looks like you have everything you need, just not quite in the right places to finish what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its higly likely I didn't get exaclty where you're looking for here, but willing to take a shot and burn an answer. The following is about as basic a logger as you can get, but demonstrates how to centralize the message-build. Included at the bottom are some test conditions, and I purposely undersized the initial buffer size to allow you walk through in a debugger and see the resizes interactively. You will no-doubt want to size that up.

Anyway, if I happened to get luck and understand the question correctly, I hope if it doesn't directly address your issue, you at least get some ideas. Thanks.

EDIT: OP requested to squelch using std::string and buffer resizing to allow conformance with the limited compilation capabilities of his embedded system environment. Fixed length buffers are used, therefore, and output from `vsnprintf()` is only trusted if content actually fit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

class Logger
{
    static const size_t STRSIZE = 256;

public:
    void error(const char* fmt, ...)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr,fmt);
        log("ERROR", fmt, argptr);
    };

    // two different logging interfaces.
    void info(const char* fmt, ...)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr,fmt);
        log("INFO", fmt, argptr);
    };

    void debug(const char* fmt, ...)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr,fmt);
        log("DEBUG", fmt, argptr);
    };

private:
    void log(const char *msg, const char* fmt, va_list& vl)
    {
        // uses a fixed size message buffer
        char str[STRSIZE+1] = {0};
        strncpy(str, msg, sizeof(str)-1);
        strncat(str, ": ", (sizeof(str)-1) - strlen(str));

        // needed for sizing limits of variadic printf, then send
        //  output as a single line message to stderr.
        size_t mlen = strlen(str);
        if (vsnprintf(str + mlen, sizeof(str)-mlen-1, fmt, vl) >= 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: (max log message length exceeded)\n", msg);
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Logger logger;

    logger.debug("Numbers %d %d %d", 1,2,3);
    logger.error("Strings %s %s %s", "1", "2", "3");
    logger.info("Mixed %s %d %p", "1", 2, "3");
    logger.info("No additional parameters required for this message.");

    // demonstrate automatic cutoff.
    char sbig[] = "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
                  "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

    logger.debug("Oversized params: %d-%s %d-%s %d-%s %d-%s", 
                 1, sbig, 2, sbig, 3, sbig, 4, sbig);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are creating a string with std::string str? Especially if you are not recommending it? Can I use a char buffer[bufsize]? Can I still "fprintf(location, "%s\n", str);" the str value?

Comment: Its the dynamic growth of the buffer behind the std::string that it is used. Note the loop for resizing until the output finally fits. If you can live with potentially partial output and a fixed output length max, certainly throw out the loop and make SURE you use the fixed buffer size for your maxlen of vsnprintf, other than that, the idea is pretty straight forward. Finally, make SURE the output buffer is terminated if you're fprintf()'ing.

Comment: Okay, even though I am including string.h I don't seem to have std::string anyway. I am on an embedded system so maybe it's not there without an installed package. What is the easiest way to null terminate? I though you just need a buffer that is a minimum one character longer than the written string?

Comment: std::string is a standard template thing. if not in your embedded compilation environment it can be stripped down, Sample has been modified to not use std::strings but rather fixed buffers and warn you if the output length would exceed the max len. I hope it is more to what you needed.